# Prove Private Key came from Apple Secure Enclave

Tags: tpm, apple

With TPM 2.0, it's possible to prove that the private key of an asymmetric key pair came from a TPM device (and thus is effectively inaccessible).

Is this possible with Apple's Secure Enclave on macOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect this is too late for you, but in case anyone else has similar question in the future, there is a new AppAttest functionality (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/devicecheck/establishing_your_app_s_integrity)

Whilst this is not quite like TPM / Android KeyStore Attestation, it can be used to prove that a key is under the control of a specific App, and that it is stored in the Enclave.

(I found your question hoping someone else had solved this ... )

Comment: Unfortunately, App Attest is not available on macOS.